# ActiveX Control will not POST to a URL in IE9 using SSL on some machines

Tags: post, ssl, active-directory, internet-explorer-9, activex

I have an issue going on and no tangible error information to go off of, but I have pinpointed the failure spot. I have an ActiveX Control that takes a locally saved word .doc file and then POSTs it to another URL.

```
  Dim WebBrowser: Set WebBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  'You can uncoment next line to see form results
  'WebBrowser.Visible = True

  'Send the form data to URL as POST request
  Dim bFormData() As Byte
  ReDim bFormData(Len(FormData) - 1)
  bFormData = StrConv(FormData, vbFromUnicode)

  WebBrowser.Navigate URL, , , bFormData, _
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Boundary + vbCrLf

  Do While WebBrowser.busy
'    Sleep 100
    DoEvents
  Loop
  WebBrowser.Quit
```

The word doc exists in the user's `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\` so that is not the issue; the file *does* exist.

The environment with the web app that contains this ActiveX control is **IE9** and the site is hosted in IIS **with a SSL cert**.

Also it works **all the time** in these conditions:

- IE7 **with** SSL
- IE8 **with** SSL
- IE9 **without** SSL

Works *on only some machines* with these conditions which is the required environment:

- IE9 with SSL

On some machines it works, on others it does not. There is no error we can find from the ActiveX Control. We can verify on the site on the server when the POST works because there is logging to receive the file. In conditions where it does not work, the POST never successfully occurs on the server and the URL to accept the file is never called.

This tells me the ActiveX control is having issue on some machines making the POST with the file, and is probably a security setting in IE9. However we have compared *all* of the IE settings across working and non-working machines and cannot find any descrepancies.

Does anyone know what security restriction could prevent this locally saved file in the user's temp directory to not successfully be picked up and uploaded via a POST to a URL? Once again it works with IE7 and IE8 with SSL and in IE9 with no SSL. However it is sporradic working in IE9 *with* SSL.

Comment: Have you solved it? My guess is, it would help if you first navigated the browser to any static page (even a blank one) on the same server over HTTPS, waited for `WebBrowser.ReadyState == ReadyState_Complete`, then did the post request. That might fix the SSL session.

Answer (score 0):

The certificates installed on each machine will vary, so this is the greatest common factor. Here is an explanation of how it affects POSTs:

> We recently determined that URLMon's code (Win8, Win7, and probably earlier) to ignore certificate revocation check failures is not applied for content uploads (e.g. HTTP POST). Hence, if a Certificate Revocation check fails, that is fatal to the upload (e.g. IE will show a Page Cannot Be Displayed error message; other clients would show a different error). However, this rarely matters in the real world because in most cases, the user first performs a download (HTTP GET) from the target HTTPS site, and as a result the server's certificate is cached with the "ignore revocation check failures" exemption for the lifetime of the process and thus a subsequent POST inherits that flag and succeeds. The upload fails if the very first request to the HTTPS site in the current process was for an upload (e.g. as in a cross-origin POST request).

Here is an explanation of how to troubleshoot:

> You can configure IE to take different actions, depending on the status of digital signatures. A signature can be unsigned, signed using valid certificates, or signed using invalid certificates.
>
> For signed or unsigned software, you can configure IE to

- Prevent downloading or running the software from a zone
- Download and run the software without user intervention from a zone
- Query users to make a choice whether to download or run the software from a zone

> How you configure IE to respond to certificates depends on various factors, such as the level of trust you have for the security zone where the content originated. If you’re deploying IE in an organization, you’ll also want to consider the level of trust you have for the intended user group and the level of technical expertise the users have. For example, you might trust unsigned software from your intranet, but not trust unsigned active content from the Internet. In that case, you would configure IE to automatically download unsigned active content from the intranet without user intervention and prevent the download of unsigned active content from the Internet.

**References**

- [Certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700805.aspx)
- [Understanding Certificate Revocation Checks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/04/07/enabling-certificate-revocation-check-failure-warnings-in-internet-explorer.aspx)
- [Certification Authority Guidance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831574.aspx)